# npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npm-install, npm-start

I have a local repo based on create-react-app. The file in the remote repo is working fine but there is a problem with the local one.

I tried running `npm install` in my local repository and an error pops up showing

`npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM`

`npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})`

`npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin`

`npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined`

`npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32`

`npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: ia32`

i also tried running `npm start` {react-scripts start} and it throwed in a bunch of errors. I am finding it difficult to understand if there is something wrong with the npm or the json file. And i don't know where the problem could be.
The main repo in my Github is fine, after cloning locally, thats where i cannot run it locally.